# How to setup spelling for same words in different languages?

Tags: neovim, spell-checking

I use vim for prose and and code, and when it comes to prose I use spelling a lot to help me out. I have it set up and already, and I'm already working with `z=, zg, zw, [s` , and `]s` to work with spelling.

The thing is, I write in both Portuguese and English, and I want some words to be valid for both languages and still be able to add specific new words to just one language, and have spelling work right.

How should I go about setting this up?

Thanks

Comment: Do you write in both Portuguese and English *in one buffer* or will some buffers be English and others Portuguese?

Comment: I use one language per buffer.

Comment: you can try to setup `spellfile` and use `1zg` or `2zg` to add good words for first or second file in `spellfile`. For my setup (I use Russian and English) I just add good/bad spelling words to a default spellfile and it works for both languages (with cyrillic and latin alphabets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above I went with this solution

```
" Spelling {{{
if has('spell')
  set nospell
  set dictionary=/user/share/dict/words
  set complete+=kspell
  " Manually Added Words Are Sent To `Names` Dictionary
  nnoremap zG 2zg
endif

function! s:ToggleSpellLanguage(lang)
  if a:lang == 'none'
    set spellfile=
    set spelllang=
    set nospell
    return
  else
    let &spellfile=expand('~/.dotfiles/vim/spell/' . a:lang . '.utf-8.add') . ',' . expand('~/.dotfiles/vim/spell/names.utf-8.add')
    if a:lang == 'en'
      set spelllang=en_us
    elseif a:lang == 'pt'
      set spelllang=pt_pt
    endif
    set spell
  endif
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 ToggleSpellLanguage call <sid>ToggleSpellLanguage(<q-args>)
" }}}
```

I use `zg` to add new words to the "language" dictionary. and `zG` to add words to the private/names dictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vim allows you to manipulate multiple spellfiles and languages in a single buffer, so it's very flexible. Your best bet is to read `:help spell.txt` and then come up with a system that works best for you.

Here's how *I* would do it. Probably your ideal solution will be slightly different.

You've said that you only use a single language per buffer, so I set a single value for `'spelllang'`, but I set two values for `'spellfile'` to facilitate adding words to both languages easily: the `zg` command will then add to the current language's `spellfile`, and the `2zg` command will add to the alternate language's `spellfile`.

Then I set up a `:LanguageToggle` command for switching languages, and a `<leader>zg` mapping for adding a word to both languages at once.

```
" Set default language
set spelllang=en_gb
set spellfile=$HOME/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add,$HOME/.vim/spell/it.utf-8.add

function! LanguageToggle() abort
  if &l:spelllang == "en_gb"
    " Switch to Italian
    setlocal spelllang=it
    setlocal spellfile=$HOME/.vim/spell/it.utf-8.add,$HOME/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
    echom "Switching to Italian"
  else
    " Switch to English
    setlocal spelllang=en_gb
    setlocal spellfile=$HOME/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add,$HOME/.vim/spell/it.utf-8.add
    echom "Switching to English"
  endif
endfunction

" Switch Languages
command! LanguageToggle call LanguageToggle()

" Add word to both spellfiles
nnoremap <leader>zg zg2zg
```

N.B. I'm using Italian, because I don't speak any Portuguese: you'll want to replace `it` with `pt` in the above.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to have different file name extension for different language, which makes it easy to set spellchecker's language based on its extension.

For example, if you write mostly in English, you can designate `.txt` to use English spelling, and `.ptxt` as Portuguese spelling.  So, an English text file might be `file1.txt` and Portuguese text might be `file2.ptxt`. (I just made up the file extension `.ptxt`. It could be anything, like `.pt` or `.pt_txt`, etc)

Then in `.vimrc`, inside the `autocmd`, add the following to load different spell checker based on filename extension (checking for either `.txt` or `.ptxt`):

```
if has("autocmd")
  augroup vimrcEx
    au! 
    "... all the autocmd goes here
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost  *.txt setlocal spell spelllang=en_gb spellfile=~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost  *.ptxt setlocal filetype=text spell spelllang=pt spellfile=~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.add
  augroup END
endif
```

Or if you want to be able to switch to different spelling by manually pressing keys:

```
nnoremap <F10> :setlocal spelllang=en_gb spellfile=~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add<CR>
nnoremap <F11> :setlocal spelllang=pt spellfile=~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.add<CR>
```

On the other hand, if you're mixing both English and Portuguese in one text:

```
setlocal spelllang=pt,en_gb
```